# Where does ArrayField create SimpleArrayField in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to review the code and maybe override it for my needs, where SimpleArrayField is created for ArrayField in Django. Unfortunately I can't find or don't understand where it happens.

I've searched through [ArrayField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa7ffc6cb3b143fb8566cbf6a387d0f032377dc7/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py#L18) and only place where [SimpleArrayField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa7ffc6cb3b143fb8566cbf6a387d0f032377dc7/django/contrib/postgres/forms/array.py#L14) is mentioned is this [method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa7ffc6cb3b143fb8566cbf6a387d0f032377dc7/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py#L188). Since method returns `super().formfield(...'form_class': SimpleArrayField...)`, I've searched for `formfield()` in inherited classes ([CheckFieldDefaultMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa7ffc6cb3b143fb8566cbf6a387d0f032377dc7/django/contrib/postgres/fields/mixins.py#L4), [Field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa7ffc6cb3b143fb8566cbf6a387d0f032377dc7/django/forms/fields.py#L46)), but found nothing.

Comment: You need to look here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa7ffc6cb3b143fb8566cbf6a387d0f032377dc7/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`models.Field.formfield()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.formfield) method returns the form field for a model field. Look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-form-field-for-model-field) to see how a form field can be overridden on a model field.

You pass a `form_class` attribute to the `formfield` method to specify which form field should be instantiated.

You've looked at the wrong `Field` (you're linking to `forms.Field` instead of `models.Field`). `ArrayField` is a `models.Field`. `SimpleArrayField` is a `forms.Field`.